# Was there a change from PrimeFaces 10.0.0 to 11.0.0 that made TreeNode into a Raw Type?

Tags: primefaces, treenode

Now, when I define a TreeNode List such as:

List node = otherNode.getChildren();

I get two warnings.

For the left side: "TreeNode is a raw type. References to generic type TreeNode should be parameterized"

For the right side: "Type safety: The expression of type List needs unchecked conversion to conform to List"

This also creates a code breaking issue when trying to use a for loop to iterate though the list like this:

for(TreeNode loopingNode : node.getChildren())
{
...
}

I receive an actual error: "Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to TreeNode"

These issues were only raised when upgrading from PrimeFaces 10.0.0 to PrimeFaces 11.0.0. Why would this be? I have looked through the migration guide (https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/11_0_0/#/../migrationguide/11_0_0), but I do not think I see anything about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. See:

- https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/pull/7525/files#diff-76612635b2ee16c50bf86c76f7b8400e887e790e9ba89e18fb4e79694f4454d1
- https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/7523

This was added in 11.0.0 RC 1. I'll add a note to the migration guide.